Shadow applied on Text is clipped in Android Compose when there is an ellipsis
The shadow effect on a Text Composable, applied using Shadow(), looks great as it aligns with the shape of the text content. This works perfectly when there’s no ellipsis, allowing the shadow to extend beyond the Text bounds. However, when the text is too long and an ellipsis appears, the shadow gets clipped within the bounds. Why does the shadow behave differently?
text without ellipsis
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello ".repeat(1),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                    shadow = Shadow(
                        Color.Black,
                        blurRadius = 30f
                    )
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(100.dp),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}


text with ellipsis
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello ".repeat(20),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                    shadow = Shadow(
                        Color.Black,
                        blurRadius = 30f
                    )
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(100.dp),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}


